# Maven : Using MySQL and MongoDB together

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb, maven, sessionfactory

In my project I have to use MySQL and mongoDB together. Hence, I have created a sessionFactory for MySQL.

The project works fine if it just uses MySQL. The moment I add the jar packages for mongoDB, I receive a NullPointerException at the line :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
```

The error that I received is as follows :

```
ERROR 2014-08-28 10:28:15,366 [http-bio-8081-exec-4][] com.bng.dbscan.dao.DbscanDao - 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bng.dbscan.dao.DbscanDao.getData(DbscanDao.java:53)
    at com.bng.dbscan.dao.DbscanDao.dbscan(DbscanDao.java:104)
    at com.bng.dbscan.controller.DbscanController.dbscan(DbscanController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any way I can use MySQL and mongoDB together using SessionFactory ? Please help me out. Thanks.

EDIT 1... SessionFactory bean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.bng.dbscan.entity.Data</value>           
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${DbConnection.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${DbConnection.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${DbConnection.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${DbConnection.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${DbConnection.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${DbConnection.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Connection Bean...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${DbConnection.JdbcDrivers}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${DbConnection.DSNurl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${DbConnection.User}" />
        <property name="password" value="${DbConnection.Password}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInSeconds" value="10" />
        <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="Select 1" />
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${DbConnection.maxConnectionsPerPartition}" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${DbConnection.minConnectionsPerPartition}" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="${DbConnection.partitionCount}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="10" />
        <property name="deregisterDriverOnClose" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

EDIT 2... pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <namexxx</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Database -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Compressing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FTP file transfer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SFTP file transfer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.51</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>xxx</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you adding jar packages if you are using Maven? What kind of SessionFactory are you using? Hibernate? Spring? Your own?

Comment: Actually, I added the artifacts of mongoDB in pom.xml. I am using Hibernate SessionFactory.

Comment: How are you defining your db connections?

Comment: I have a properties file which has the connection and I access the properties through the beans... This is the bean for the connection for sessionfactory

PLS chk the edit...

Comment: you know that MongoDB doesn't understand the concept of transaction? and the idea of a session is also a bit different

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan ... I am not using the transaction properties for mongoDB. Its for MySQL. My issue is that mysql/hibernate sessionFactory stops working (sessionfactory remains null) when I add the mongoDB artifacts in pom.xml. I havn't even started using mongoDB TBH... Its giving error even before that.

Comment: please post your pom.xml then

Answer (score 0):

It probably has absolutely nothing to do with the fact you are using mongo together with mysql. Can you show us the relevant code of:

`DbscanDao.getData()`, more specifically, line 53.

It is where the exception occurs, 100% has nothing to do with mongo or hibernate being used together.

Comment: Line #53 is .. Session session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(); (I have mentioned it above). I tried two instances. I removed the mongoDB artifacts from the pom.xml and ran the project... It gave no error. After that I added the artifacts and ran. It showed the same error. I know its strange, but some how mongoDb artifacts are affecting the sessionfactory session.